# $\alpha|f(x-y)| = \beta|f(x-y)||g(y)|$ a.e. implies $g(y)$ is constant a.e

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have two functions $f,g \in L^1$  on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $||f||_1 > 0$ and  for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ not both $0$, $\alpha|f(x-y)| = \beta|f(x-y)||g(y)|$ for almost all $x$ and almost all $y$. Does this  imply $g(y)$ is constant almost everywhere?

We could almost just divide by $f(x-y)$ but we have to deal with $f(x-y)$ being $0$. I feel like you should be able to argue that since $||f||_1 > 0$, $f$ is positive on some set $A$ of measure greater than $0$. So for any $y$, we would translate $\alpha|f(x-y)| = \beta|f(x-y)||g(y)|$ by some $x$ such that $x-y$ is in $A$ and thus we can divide by $f(x-y)$ to get that $|g(y)| = \alpha/\beta$ a.e.. But I cant quite formalize this.

Comment: It is necessary that $\alpha,\beta\ne 0.$

Comment: @mfl ahh yes i will add that

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct. The formal details are the following:

First of all i assume that $g\geq 0$. Since if you wanna keep the absolute value on $g$ then it is not true, for example take $\alpha=\beta=1$ and $g(y)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(y)-\mathbb{1}_{[2,3]}(y)$ (here $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ is indicator function on $A$) then the condition
$$\tag{*}\alpha|f(x-y)|=\beta |f(x-y)||g(y)|$$
is true for all integrable $f$, but $g$ is not constant. Also, we need to assume that $\alpha,\beta \neq 0$. Since, if $\beta=0$ this forces immediately $\alpha=0$ because $f$ cannot be $0$ a.e. Now, if $\alpha=0$ and $\beta\neq 0$ with similar argument as before we conlude that $g=0$ a.e. and we are done in this case. So we suppose that $g\geq 0$ and that $\alpha,\beta\neq 0$. Now, let
$$A_y=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\, (*)\, \text{ holds for the pair }\, (x,y)\}$$
The assumption that $(*)$ holds for almost every $x$ and almost every $y$ means that $$\tag{1}\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus A_y)=0$$
for almost all $y$, and that
$$\tag{2}\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)=0$$
where $A=\{y\in \mathbb{R}:\, \mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus A_y)=0\}$. Now, let
$B_y=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\, |f(x-y)|>0\}$
.Then, using the translation invariance of the integral, for all $y$ we have,
\begin{align}
||f||_1&=\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|\,d\mu(x)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x-y)|\,d\mu(x)\\
&=\int_{B_y}|f(x-y)|\,d\mu(x)>0
\end{align}
The last inequality implies that $\mu(B_y)>0$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. We claim that for all $y\in A$ there is $x$ such that $|f(x-y)|>0$. Indeed, pick $y\in A$. Then, $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus A_y)=0$ and $\mu(B_y)>0$ implies that $A_y\cap B_y\neq 0$. But, now for $x\in A_y\cap B_y$ we have that $(*)$ holds for the pair $(x,y)$ and that $|f(x-y)|>0$ which implies that $|g(y)|=\alpha/ \beta$. Hence, $g$ is constant on $A$ and since $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ has zero measure it follows that $g$ is constant almost everywhere.